# SimpleMessageStore was out of capacity for group , try constructing it with a larger capacity exception

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration application and are getting below SimpleMessageStore out of capacity exception for each request in console log.

Note- We are getting the proper response from backend service with 200 status code but still see this error in console log for each reqeust. We also tried to initialized  SimpleMessageStore() with default constructor but getting same exception.

1. Step-1 Exception -

[image]

As of now, we've configured following property for IntegrationFlows sctter gather but no luck to remove this exception from console log. is it known behavior of spring-integration-core-5.5.10 version to print this log in console or do we need to add any other property to avoid this exception from console?

2. Code Snippet - This code is being used to call another HTTP endpoints.

[image]

Step -3 : This is spring SimpleMessageStore class source code. It's part of spring-integration-core-5.5.10.jar. SimpleMessageStore class source code for reference :
[image]

Comment: That line of code (`SimpleMessageStore.java:282`) is not about throwing exception. It is just its instance creation. Not clear what is that screen you show us. Perhaps it would help if you share with us a simple project how to reproduce.

Comment: @ArtemBilan :Agree with you, SimpleMessageStore is spring class which I've highlighted only. As per line number 282, it's just creation of exception instance but if you see the step-1 exception stackflow, this exception is thrown internally. Code snippet I've mentioned in Step-2.

Comment: I know that Spring code: I wrote it myself. Your comment is not helpful - sorry. Such an exception cannot be thrown since `applySequence` on the `RecipientListRouter` of your configuration is only a request message id. Then you distribute this message into two channels. So, it definitely cannot overcome `500` items you configure. Therefore that's a reason why I'm asking about simple project to reproduce on our side. It is perhaps only your Eclipse feature to log every single exception instance created in the program...

Comment: Sure, . One more thing, In my local eclipse, this issue is not reproduceable.  This issue is reproduceable on our kubernetes container environment after deploy our service. And this SimpleMessageStore exception is printed in Dynatrace for each API call.

Comment: How is it reproduceable? What fail for your container? Just some print in Dynatrace ? So, probably this is the question to that tool then? How about if you don't use that Dynatrace? Will you still say that there is a problem? That's really was my question in the beginning: the problem you show does not make sense from your code perspective and stack trace you show - they just don't correlate with each other. Although we really see a Scatter-Gather mentioning in that stack trace. I definitely would like to understand the problem and see where the framework is wrong to fix, but I fail so far...

Comment: Do you have some custom message id generation? If that is the same then we can reproduce the issue with something like `250-260` concurrent requests when the request message id is the same. Meanwhile we just figured out that it is not OK to pre-build `Exception` instances: it mislead us where exactly the error has happened in the code.

Comment: ok, let me collect custom message id  and will also check at Dynatrace side from which layer it's getting this exception. will share the result with you once we collect this details. (One more observation, I call one API through postman instead of concurrent requests, At that time also, we see this exception)

Comment: Answer of your query - 
How is it reproduceable? - We deploy the service on kube environment and call the rest API endpoints from postman one time, -> Go to Dynatrace and see the API call distribute details -> dynatrace show 200 HTTP status code and we see the valid response in postman but Dynatrace "Error" tab, show this error message.   
What fail for your container? - Don't see any failure in container logs
Just some print in Dynatrace ? - Yes, it's printed in Dynatrace only. We started to check from which layer dyantrace fetching this exception.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - We've identified the root cause of this issue. Dynatrace logs an exception instance even if it is not thrown. Here are one test case which we validate.
Let me

Comment: Sounds good, but don't look like you have finished. Please, try to share with us something what we can reproduce on  our side and see if there is anything has to be fixed on our side. Not sure what is that Dynatrace, how it works and how that `new MessagingException()` is logged without being thrown.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan - Dynatrace logs an exception instance even if it is not thrown. As you know, SimpleMessageStore line number 282 is a instance creation but it's printing in Dynatrace which is misleading. For reproducing this behavior, We created the instance only of  MessageExeception instead of throwing any exception at code level but still we saw exception in Dynatrace. 
will share the testcase screenshot to reproduce and Dynatrace details also.

Comment: Uh! Isn't this a fault of that Dynatrace tool? Why would one print exceptions just because they are created? I believe you need to share your experience with them. According to their landing page this service is not free: https://www.dynatrace.com/

Comment: Wow! That sounds freaky. It is a bit odd to create an exception that might, or might not, be thrown, but that behavior (logging on creation) seems totally wrong.

Comment: @SohanPoonia, would you mind to answer your own question to explain what is going on with Dynatrace and how have you solved the problem? This will help other community members with similar findings.

Comment: Sure @ArtemBilan, We're working with Dynatrace team to collect some details. Once I get that information, i'll put the consolidate details in answer of this question. Meanwhile are you going to raise any JIRA ticket at your side to create the instance of MessageException on line number 287 and 305 instead of 282 in future release?

Comment: Here is that fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/308f3fadeb46526780cf53a025e113db815883b3. We are not going to back-port it, since it is not critical and may cause some breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the root cause of this issue internally at Dynatrace side :
We're using Dynatrace to capture the spring integration logs.  Dynatrace logs an exception instance even it's just declared instead of throw the exception.
As you know, SimpleMessageStore line number 282 is a instance creation but it's printing in Dynatrace which is misleading.
Our internal Dynatrace team trying to disable the jvm trace property to mitigate this issue. I'll update this answer once I get the actual property name of Dynatrace.

Some additional information : This is one alternate approach if we don't want to explicitly make any changes on Dynatrace.

Artem Bilan and team made the changes in SImpleMessageStore class to create an exception that will be thrown only.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/308f3fadeb46526780cf53a025e113db815883b3